# How to "cast" a std::vector<char> to std::vector<wchar_t>

Tags: c++, stl

I have a std::vector of bytes (`char`), I'd like to do the equivalent of just *"C-style casting"* this vector to a vector which is of type `wchar_t`.

Obviously, what I really have to do is to copy the data, but the thing here is that I already have an UTF-16 byte stream on the left side, I just wanna move that over to the `wchar_t` vector so that I can use it. Ideally, I'd like to just swap the buffer, but I'm not sure how to do that in safe manner...

What's the C++ way of doing an as efficient as safe conversion copy operation allows?

## NOTE:

I do store my UTF-16 strings as `std::wstring` or `std::vector<wchar_t>` but I have this memory buffer that I happen to know is UTF-16, and I need to copy it, somehow...

Comment: What? You have UTF-16 data stored as `char`? Btw. the conversion from `char` to `wchar_t` is done using `widen`, but I guess, that's not what you want http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/widen/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/196097/Converting-ANSI-to-Unicode-and-back?display=Print may answer it

Comment: And to extend Let_Me_Be's comment: Why do you have UTF-16 data stored as `char`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Makes it is so you don't have to worry about silly things like byte order O.o

Comment: @JohnLeidegren if the vector<char> 's content is utf-16 , then you can ideally pass it as a wchar_t pointer with &v[0] without issues, the real question i have is how did you get utf-16 packed into a vector char? Network code?

Comment: If you are storing text (UTF-16), why not use `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`?

Comment: No, what I do is that I load a text file into a memory buffer (this is my `std::vector<uint8>` sequence of bytes, to be specific). I then employ a simple heuristic, where I look at the first bytes to determine the encoding. If I find the UTF-16 byte order mark, I know that all I really need is to change the way I look at these bytes and that's it. And preferably I'd like to somehow marshal the contents from my memory buffer over to my text buffer without really copying the entire buffer. Copying isn't really a problem, but I'm looking for a simple way to just make that transition.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren:  I removed the screaming from your edit.  Please keep in mind that we are trying in good faith to help you.

Comment: @JohnDibling I know you are, I was just trying to put some emphasis on why I consider this to be a non-trivial problem.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren:  I have a meeting in 1 minute, so I'm going to delete my current answer until such a time as I can get you a better answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most efficient (and sanest) way to do it is to not do it. Let your `vector<char>` own the data buffer, and simply create a pair of `wchar_t` pointers to use as iterators pointing into the vector.

```
std::vector<char> vec;
wchar_t* first = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&vec[0]);
wchar_t* last = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&vec[0] + vec.size());
```

Now you have an iterator pair that'll work just fine with all the standard library algorithms.
And you didn't have to copy a single byte. :)

(Disclaimer: I'm assuming that the vector's size is divisible by `sizeof(wchar_t)`. Otherwise you'll have to adjust the `last` pointer)

Comment: That's dead on, and then I can just use assign and that will copy the stuff, right? It's fine to copy it in my mind, I was just hoping for a swap trick. I mean, the internals of a std::vector are the same, I just wanna swap out the innards (like a `reinterpret_cast`), but this will do nicely.

Comment: `static_cast` would do just fine.

Comment: @AlexandreC: I think `static_cast` would be undefined behavior.  I also think it wouldn't work in practice, depending on if the vector stores a size or end-pointer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: `static_cast` is never more UB than `reinterpret_cast` and will work just as fine when casting between (non function) pointers.

Comment: Does this violate strict aliasing rules or alignment rules?

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<char> v1;
std::vector<wchar_t> v2;

wchar_t *begin = (wchar_t *) &v2.front();
wchar_t *end   = (wchar_t *) (&v2.back() + 1);

v1.assign(begin, end);
```

I haven't tested this, but I can't imagine that something like this wouldn't work... If you have endian issues, this would become quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Use `&v2.back() + 1` rather than `end()`, since `end()` returns an iterator. Confusingly, it might appear to work since the iterator happens to be a pointer, and then stop working later (on another implementation or with a debug version of `vector`).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<char> v1;
std::vector<wchar_t> v2;

const char * cv1 = v1.data();

const wchar_t * cv2 = static_cast<const wchar_t *>(cv1);
std::copy(cv2, cv2 + v1.size() / sizeof(wchar_t), std::back_inserter(v2));
```